# Twitter API posts that include link and hashtag, don't show up for that hashtag on Twitter

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, hashtag

I have a blog that allows readers to post their comments on a post directly into wordpress. I also include that hashtag of the relevant post as an initial value for the form field. When the comment is posted, it displays correctly on twitter's page with the hashtag. However, when I include a url in the comment, it display perfectly fine on twitter user's timeline, but wont show up on the hashtag page.

I think it has to do with php automagically putting in escape slashes in with form inputs, since comments that include an apostrophe, display with escape slashes on twitter as well. for example:

it\'s a sunny day.

what gives?